# How to work with arrays using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm creating a search bar using jQuery and my code is pasted below

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/fpLf1to4/

```
var inputSearch     = $('.searchInput').hide(); 
var searchArray     = ['s','e','a','r','c','h'];
var searchReturn    = '';

$('#search').on('click', function(){

    $(inputSearch).fadeToggle(500).focus();


    for(var i = 0 ; i < searchArray.length ; i++){

        searchReturn = searchReturn + searchArray[i];

    }   

    $(inputSearch).attr('placeholder', searchReturn[0]);

});
```

Note : now I'm using only the first index of the array for my input attribute.

`$(inputSearch).attr('placeholder', searchReturn[0]);`

Now after every one second I want my `attr()` to be updated like

`$(inputSearch).attr('placeholder', searchReturn[0] + searchReturn[1]);`

and the very next second

`$(inputSearch).attr('placeholder', searchReturn[0] + searchReturn[1] + searchReturn[2]);`

and so on ...

Comment: Use setTimout to add the following letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function, instead of `for` loop.  Here is how you can do it:

```
$('#search').on('click', function(){
        $(inputSearch).fadeToggle(500).focus();

        var i = 0; 
        var interval = setInterval(function() {            
            searchReturn = searchReturn + searchArray[i];            
            $(inputSearch).attr('placeholder', searchReturn);
            if(i == searchArray.length - 1) {
              clearInterval(interval)    
            }
            i++;
        }, 2000);   

    });
```

And here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fpLf1to4/1/

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you wanted?
You can change the timeout if you want execution to be faster or slower.

```
var inputSearch     = $('.searchInput').hide(); 
var searchArray     = ['s','e','a','r','c','h'];
var searchReturn    = '';

$('#search').on('click', function(){
    $(inputSearch).fadeToggle(500).focus();
    updateSearch();     
});

var currentIdx = 0;
function updateSearch() {
    var placeholder = $(inputSearch).attr('placeholder')
    if (placeholder === undefined) {
        placeholder = "";
    }

    placeholder += searchArray[currentIdx];
    $(inputSearch).attr('placeholder', placeholder);


    currentIdx++;
    if (currentIdx >= searchArray.length) {
        return;
    }
    setTimeout(updateSearch,500);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fpLf1to4/6/

Comment: Update your fiddle link.

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `.queue()` , `setTimeout`

```
    var inputSearch = $('.searchInput').hide();
    var searchArray = ['s', 'e', 'a', 'r', 'c', 'h'];

    $('#search').on('click', function() {       
      inputSearch.queue("s", [])
      .attr("placeholder", "")
      .fadeToggle(500).focus()
      .queue("s", $.map(searchArray, function(value) {
          return function(next) {
            $(this).attr("placeholder", function(_, p) {
              return p === undefined ? value : p + value
            });
            setTimeout(next, 1000)
          }
        })).dequeue("s")
    });
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fpLf1to4/5/